# How to solve freezing of LibreOffice 7 on Mac OS X Sierra issue?

Tags: freeze, crash, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, macos-highsierra

Using LibreOffice 7 (Calc) on Mac OS X High Sierra.

It constantly freezes (turning colored wheel) so I have to force quit it.

How should I proceed to find the cause? Is there a log somewhere that I can access to get more information about the problem?

**Update**

- Freezing seems to occur often upon clicking on a cell, but it also happens after a given time when the file is open without touching it.
- Freezing happens when an external screen is connected, but also (less?) when it is disconnected.
- At one occasion, after force quitting and reopening the document, the text "X0003" (not sure about the number of zeros) was inserted in the document at the location where I was typing during the last freeze.

Answer (score 1):

You could try resetting your LibreOffice profile by renaming the folder (~/Library/Application Support/LibreOffice/4/user).

You could also try going to System Preferences -> Displays -> Color and select 'Generic RGB Profile'. Try opening LibreOffice again after changing this setting. If the problem does not persist, you can try changing the color profile back and seeing if this occurs again.

Comment: Thank you. The problem still persists after these 2 steps.

Answer (score 1):

My aunt has an older iMac that will only upgrade to High Sierra.
She has taken over some financial responsibilities for an organization and needs to update existing Microsoft Office Excel files. I've been using LibreOffice for years and suggested she use it too. Well, we found that it would randomly and frequently crash with spinning beach ball cursor and the only option to force quit it.

Thinking it was a problem with the newest version of LibreOffice and High Sierra, I removed it (and all its associated files), then installed an older version, but that had the same problem.

Then out of ideas about what to do, I searched for downloaded High Sierra Java from Apple's site. It downloaded with an (1) after the file name, so it seems that I had already downloaded it before when setting up High Sierra for her, but it let me install it again (or maybe I never installed it before..??).. Anyway, after installing the Java update, we worked on the .xlxs file for 20 minutes or more without it crashing.. Before it was crashing every couple of minutes.

Try install/reinstalling Java for macOS 2017-001 to see if that helps:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US